# Creating a gallery app for Android

Tags: java, android, client-server

I want to create an app that takes pictures from an online gallery and displays them fullscreen in a flick-left/flick-right fashion. The thing is that if the online gallery is updated I want the pictures in the app to be updated as well ! AND I don't want all of the pictures to be stored on SD due to memory issues but rather be loaded from the URL. And pointers in the right direction and help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking for the whole code or do you have a specific problem in your code?

Comment: I havn't really started as I don't know which approach to take. I'm not asking for the whole code but rather a concept. For example, I don't know whether to make a client-side image array and then push the images from the server whenever I want to update the images in the app or just make an online gallery that links to the android app. I want to try the second approach and I want to see how it can be implemented. I don't want the whole code lol...

Comment: Your problem consists of multiple sub-problems. Which of the sub-problems is the one that you have issues with? Are you able to create parts of this app successfully if you leave this specific sub-problem out?

Comment: Hi Arno thanks for your comment. 
My biggest issue right now is the psuedo-code, CAN I make an online gallery which links to an android application and the images in the android application get updated automatically whenever I upload a newer image to the online gallery? And ofcourse who can update to this online gallery is restricted. It's like a photo of the day app, only I'm using it for the emergency services here at my university. So that's my biggest issue, can it be done, and if yes then how.

Second biggest issue is the flick-left and flick-right; which I'll get to later.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Volley library](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138) together with [viewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

also, you can check out the [bitmapFun sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), which shows the gallery in both gridView and viewPager .

Comment: also if memory is an issue isn't it better that I just load jpegs instead of bmps? I know n00b question but I'm new to java.

Comment: it has nothing to do with java. same goes on all programming languages. it doesn't matter which format you use for showing the images. the format affect how much the image takes on the storage (not RAM) ,how fast it is to decode and how well it's compressed compared to its quality. after decoding the image, you get a bitmap (a bunch of pixels to show). there isn't much you can do without decreasing the quality of the image. you could however downscale the image to the screen, since the screen might not be able to show all of the bitmap (in case its resolution is lower than the bitmap itself).

Comment: btw, you should never use bitmaps files . instead, use either jpg, png, or webP . bitmaps are not compressed and take a lot of storage. if quality (or transparency) is very important for you, use PNG (or webP). if storage is more important for you (and you don't have transparency in the image) , use JPG ( or webP).